# The convenience init defined within the extension of UIHostingController cannot be used in a subclass

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode15

I have defined a convenience init within the UIHostingController, intending to call it from a subclass. However, while it compiles without errors in Xcode 14.2, it generates an error in Xcode 15.

```
extension UIHostingController {
    convenience init(rootView: Content, ignoreSafeArea: Bool) {
        self.init(rootView: rootView)
    }
}

class CustomUIHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> { }

struct Profile: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Profile")
    }
}

CustomUIHostingController(rootView: Profile(), ignoreSafeArea: true) // error: Extra argument 'ignoreSafeArea' in call
```

What could be the cause of this?

After updating from Xcode 14 to Xcode 15, I encountered a compilation error when building the project. It appears that the convenience init defined in the superclass cannot be accessed from the subclass.

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need `CustomUIHostingController`?

Answer (score 1):

You're right.the change in behavior between Xcode 14 and Xcode 15 is due to a change in the Swift compiler in Xcode 14, the compiler allowed convenience initializers to be called from subclasses, even if the superclass initializer had different arguments.however, in Xcode 15, the compiler is stricter about enforcing the rules for calling initializers.

The rule for convenience initializers is that they must call a designated initializer from the same class. A designated initializer is an initializer that initializes all of the required properties of the class.

If you remove the convenience initializer, you will need to call the designated initializer explicitly from your subclass.

I hope this example shows you :

```
class CustomUIHostingController<Content: View>: UIHostingController<Content> {
    init(rootView: Content, ignoreSafeArea: Bool) {
        super.init(rootView: rootView, coder: nil)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same errors but only for `UIHostingController`. I had to expose the additional initialization as a method such as `func ignoreSafeArea()`, calling it explicitly after the initialization.

At same time, I found that calling super convenience init methods from subclass works well for other classes.

Even subclasses and extension defined in different modules.

So I think this should be a bug from Xcode 15.

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    convenience init(foo: Bool) {
        self.init()
    }
}

class FooViewController: UIViewController {
    
}

let fooViewController = FooViewController(foo: false) // no errors

class Foo<T>: NSObject {
    let bar: T
    
    init(bar: T) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

extension Foo {
    convenience init(boo: T, boolean: Bool) {
        self.init(bar: boo)
    }
}

class Fux<T>: Foo<T> {
    
}

let fux = Fux(boo: 0, boolean: false) // no errors
```